# Retrieving objects from many-to-many column and placing into new table

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have an Event table that holds 2 types of attendees: students and staff. How would I go about retrieving those who are in the student column(many-to-many) and placing them into their own table?

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    students = models.ManyToManyField(StudentProfile, null=True, blank=True)
    staff = models.ManyToManyField(StaffProfile, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

new table: ?

```
class StudentAttendees(models.Model):
    profile = models.ManyToManyField(StudentProfile, through='Event')
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

returns:

```
django.core.management.base.CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
profiles.studentattendees: 'profile' is a manually-defined m2m relation through model Event, which does not have foreign keys to StudentProfile and StudentAttendees
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
for some_event in Event.objects.all():
    student_attendees_object = StudentAttendees.objects.create(event=some_event)
    for student in some_event.students_set.all():
        student_attendees_objects.profile.add(student)
```

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but if you need extra info on the student attendees, you might wanna look into an intermediate table with the `through` parameter. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) on this.

Comment: I think so that the intermediate model with through parameter is what you need.

Comment: Just to clarify. I'm retrieving the student attendees to mainly display them for backend use only. Just to have for a better way to view the attendees in a list. Sorry I didn't specify that in my post.

Comment: @msc should this be a model.Manager?